# Passing a string array to a function to be altered

Tags: c, arrays

so currently I am running a program to generate a bundle of files at random, then have them connect to each other, and create a maze like game. 
I'm trying to build an array of the file paths to pass to a function so it can be generated then the array can be worked on some more by the calling function. What's happening is that is generating the array but leaving the first element(filepath[0]) blank thus seg. faulting on me. But when I set a breakpoint, all other sections of the array are fine, just not the first element. It's been about 9 months since I wrote and C and I'm unsure where my pointer hiccup is coming from, thank you all in advanced

Here is the code so far

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void create_files(char (*filepath[7]));

int main(){
    time_t t;
    char *filepath[7];
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        filepath[i] = malloc(60);


    create_files(filepath);
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        free(filepath[i]);
    return 0;
}

void create_files(char (*filepath[7])){
    int i = 0, pid = getpid(),q = 0,random, r=7;
    char procid[20];
    sprintf(procid, "%d", pid);
    char directory[80] = "./dringb.rooms.";

    strcat(directory,procid);
    int newdir = mkdir(directory, 0777);

    for (q = 0; q < 7; q++)
        filepath[q] = directory;

    char *bigrooms[10] ={"/Bridge.txt","/Gate.txt","/Hallway.txt",
        "/Dungeon.txt","/Galley.txt","/Throne.txt","/Boss.txt", "/Lab.txt",
        "/Torture.txt", "/Courtyard.txt"};
    bool redflag = false;
    char *rooms[7];
    q = 0;

    while (q != 7){ //grabs the rooms at random from the set of bigrooms
        random = rand()%10;
        for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            if (rooms[i] == bigrooms[random])
                redflag = true;
        }
        if (redflag == false){
            rooms[q] = bigrooms[random];
            redflag = false;
            q++;
        }
        else
            redflag = false;
    }

    char **dest = (char **)malloc(r * sizeof(char *));
    for (i=0; i<r; i++)
        dest[i] = (char *)malloc(8 * sizeof(rooms)); //allocates each room a new space

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        strcat(dest[i], directory);
        strcat(dest[i],rooms[i]);
        filepath[i] = dest[i]; //creates directory path for each room.txt
    }


    int usedrooms[4];
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        FILE *f = fopen(filepath[i], "w");
        fputs("Roomname: ", f);
        fputs(rooms[i],f);
        fputs("\n",f);
        fclose(f);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        FILE *f = fopen(filepath[i], "a+");
        for (q = 0; q < 4; q++)
            usedrooms[q] = 100;
        int roomrand, q = 0, z = 0, connrooms = 3;
        bool greenflag = true, retry = false;

        roomrand = rand() %2;
        if (roomrand == 1)
            connrooms = 4;

        while (q != connrooms){ //prevents from having a connection to same room
            do{
                retry = false;
                roomrand = rand() % 7;
                for(z = 0; z < 4; z++){
                    if (roomrand == usedrooms[z])
                        retry = true;
                }
            }while(roomrand == i || retry == true); //prevents from having a connection to same room
            bool found = false;
            char buffer[100];
            rewind(f);
            while(fscanf(f,"%s", buffer) == 1){
                if (strcmp(buffer,rooms[roomrand]) == 0)//prevents a double connecting room from being added
                    greenflag = false;
            }
            if(greenflag == true){
                usedrooms[q] = roomrand;
                fputs("Connecting Room: ", f);
                fputs(rooms[roomrand],f);
                fputs("\n",f);
            }

            fclose(f);
            greenflag = true;
            found = false;
            FILE *f2 = fopen(filepath[roomrand],"a+");
            rewind(f2);
            while(fscanf(f2,"%s", buffer) == 1){
                if (strcmp(buffer,rooms[i]) == 0) //prevents a double connecting room from being added
                    found = true;
            }
            if (found == false){
                fputs("Connecting Room: ",f2);
                fputs(rooms[i],f2);
                fputs("\n",f2);
            }
            fclose(f2);
            fopen(filepath[i],"a+");
            found = false;
            q++;
        }
        q = 0;
        fclose(f);
    }

    int usedroomtype[7];
    int roomrand;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        usedroomtype[i] = 100;

    for (i = 0; i < 7;i++){
        do{
            redflag = false;
            roomrand = rand() % 7;
            for (q = 0; q < 7; q++)
                if (roomrand == usedroomtype[q])
                    redflag = true;
        } while (redflag == true);
        usedroomtype[i] = roomrand;
        FILE *fp = fopen(filepath[roomrand], "a+");
        if (i == 0)
            fputs("Room Type: Start Room", fp);
        else if (i == 6)
            fputs("Room Type: End Room",fp);
        else
            fputs ("Room Type: Mid Room",fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }

}
```

Comment: `free (filepath);` is incorrect. `filepath` is in automatic storage, you never `malloc` any space for it, so you shouldn't `free` it either.

Comment: When you `malloc` memory, it is *not* initialized. So `strcat` won't work unless you initialize the memory first. The line `strcat(dest[i], directory)` should be `strcpy(dest[i], directory)`.

Comment: The line `dest[i] = (char *)malloc(8 * sizeof(rooms));` doesn't seem right to me. Seems like that should be `dest[i] = malloc(80);` since 80 is the size you choose for the `directory` variable.

Comment: Just in general I'd recommend breaking the `create_files` function up into a few functions. There's a lot of code there, declarations all over the place, loops everywhere. I don't think you need to `malloc` at all. You should only `malloc` if 1) You need access to the memory outside of the current function 2) You don't know how much you will need until runtime 3) You need "a lot" of memory. I'd recommend putting everything in automatic storage (most likely the stack) for this.

Comment: `char (*filepath[7])` as a parameter means the same as `char **filepath`. (Which is OK, but it's an unconventional way of writing it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array is being passed correctly. The problem is that data is getting corrupted.

```
for (q = 0; q < 7; q++)
    filepath[q] = directory;
```

This is invalid. It should be `strcpy(filepath[q], directory);` It's okay to set for example `char *temp = filepath[q]`, because `temp` was not allocated. But `filepath[q]` is already allocated. Use `strcpy` to to change it value.

Later there is a similar error

```
char **dest = (char **)malloc(r * sizeof(char *));
for (i=0; i<r; i++)
    dest[i] = (char *)malloc(8 * sizeof(rooms));

for (i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    strcat(dest[i], directory);
    strcat(dest[i],rooms[i]);
    filepath[i] = dest[i]; //creates directory path for each room.txt
}
```

Two things. First, `dest` is not initialized. Always start with `strcpy` with uninitialized string, then use `strcat`. Second, use `strcpy` to change the value of `filepath[i]` as explained earlier. `dest` is actually not needed. You could just copy directly to `filepath`

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    strcpy(filepath[i], directory);
    strcat(filepath[i], rooms[i]);
}
```

As mentioned in comments, allocation for `filepath` should be larger. `directory` is max 80 bytes, `room` is max 10 bytes, so `filepath` should be max 90 bytes.

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    filepath[i] = malloc(90);
```

Also some values are not initialized, example `char *rooms[7];`

Elsewhere:

```
int pid = getpid();
char procid[20];
sprintf(procid, "%d", pid);
char directory[80] = "./dringb.rooms.";
strcat(directory,procid);
```

You are already using `sprintf`, you can simplify this as follows:

```
sprintf(directory, "./dringb.rooms.%d", getpid());
```

Example:

```
int main()
{
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    char *filepath[7];
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        filepath[i] = malloc(90);

    create_files(filepath);

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        printf("%s\n", filepath[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        free(filepath[i]);

    return 0;
}
void create_files(char *filepath[7])
{
    int i = 0, random;
    char directory[80];
    sprintf(directory, "./dringb.rooms.%d", getpid());
    //mkdir(directory);
    mkdir(directory, 0777);

    int q;
    for (q = 0; q < 7; q++) strcpy(filepath[q], directory);

    char *bigrooms[20] ={"/Bridge.txt","/Gate.txt","/Hallway.txt","/Dungeon.txt","/Galley.txt","/Throne.txt","/Boss.txt", "/Lab.txt","/Torture.txt", "/Courtyard.txt"};
    bool redflag = false;
    char *rooms[7];
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) rooms[i] = 0;

    q = 0;
    while (q != 7)
    {
        //grabs the rooms at random from the set of bigrooms
        random = rand()%10;
        for(i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            if (rooms[i] == bigrooms[random])
                redflag = true;
        }

        if (redflag == false)
        {
            rooms[q] = bigrooms[random];
            redflag = false;
            q++;
        }
        else
            redflag = false;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        strcpy(filepath[i], directory);
        strcat(filepath[i], rooms[i]);
    }

    int usedrooms[4];
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        FILE *f = fopen(filepath[i], "w");
        fputs("Roomname: ", f);
        fputs(rooms[i],f);
        fputs("\n",f);
        fclose(f);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        FILE *f = fopen(filepath[i], "a+");
        for (q = 0; q < 4; q++)
            usedrooms[q] = 100;
        int roomrand, q = 0, z = 0, connrooms = 3;
        bool greenflag = true, retry = false;

        roomrand = rand() %2;
        if (roomrand == 1)
            connrooms = 4;

        while (q != connrooms)
        { //prevents from having a connection to same room
            do
            {
                retry = false;
                roomrand = rand() % 7;
                for(z = 0; z < 4; z++)
                {
                    if (roomrand == usedrooms[z])
                        retry = true;
                }
            }
            while(roomrand == i || retry == true); //prevents from having a connection to same room

            bool found = false;
            char buffer[100];
            rewind(f);
            while(fscanf(f,"%s", buffer) == 1)
            {
                if (strcmp(buffer,rooms[roomrand]) == 0)//prevents a double connecting room from being added
                    greenflag = false;
            }

            if(greenflag == true)
            {
                usedrooms[q] = roomrand;
                fputs("Connecting Room: ", f);
                fputs(rooms[roomrand],f);
                fputs("\n",f);
            }

            fclose(f);
            greenflag = true;
            found = false;
            FILE *f2 = fopen(filepath[roomrand],"a+");
            rewind(f2);

            while(fscanf(f2,"%s", buffer) == 1)
            {
                if (strcmp(buffer,rooms[i]) == 0) //prevents a double connecting room from being added
                    found = true;
            }

            if (found == false)
            {
                fputs("Connecting Room: ",f2);
                fputs(rooms[i],f2);
                fputs("\n",f2);
            }

            fclose(f2);
            fopen(filepath[i],"a+");
            found = false;
            q++;
        }
        q = 0;
        fclose(f);
    }

    int usedroomtype[7];
    int roomrand;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        usedroomtype[i] = 100;

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            redflag = false;
            roomrand = rand() % 7;
            for (q = 0; q < 7; q++)
                if (roomrand == usedroomtype[q])
                    redflag = true;
        }
        while (redflag == true);

        usedroomtype[i] = roomrand;
        FILE *fp = fopen(filepath[roomrand], "a+");
        if (i == 0)
            fputs("Room Type: Start Room", fp);
        else if (i == 6)
            fputs("Room Type: End Room",fp);
        else
            fputs ("Room Type: Mid Room",fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great thank you so much, C strings are a pain coming from C++ and python